# Django: merging objects

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, cascade

I have such model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    # and so on
```

Since I'm importing them from many sources, and users of my website are able to add new Places, I need a way to merge them from an admin interface. Problem is, name is not very reliable since they can be spelled in many different ways, etc
I'm used to use something like this:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True) # canonical
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    # and so on

class PlaceName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
```

query like this

```
Place.objects.get(placename__name='St Paul\'s Cathedral', city=london)
```

and merge like this

```
class PlaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ('merge', )

    def merge(self, request, queryset):
        main = queryset[0]
        tail = queryset[1:]

        PlaceName.objects.filter(place__in=tail).update(place=main)
        SomeModel1.objects.filter(place__in=tail).update(place=main)
        SomeModel2.objects.filter(place__in=tail).update(place=main)
        # ... etc ...

        for t in tail:
            t.delete()

        self.message_user(request, "%s is merged with other places, now you can give it a canonical name." % main)
    merge.short_description = "Merge places"
```

as you can see, I have to update all other models with FK to Place with new values. But it's not very good solution since I have to add every new model to this list.

How do I "cascade update" all foreign keys to some objects prior to deleting them?

Or maybe there are other solutions to do/avoid merging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone intersted, here is really generic code for this:

```
def merge(self, request, queryset):
    main = queryset[0]
    tail = queryset[1:]

    related = main._meta.get_all_related_objects()

    valnames = dict()
    for r in related:
        valnames.setdefault(r.model, []).append(r.field.name)

    for place in tail:
        for model, field_names in valnames.iteritems():
            for field_name in field_names:
                model.objects.filter(**{field_name: place}).update(**{field_name: main})

        place.delete()

    self.message_user(request, "%s is merged with other places, now you can give it a canonical name." % main)
```

Comment: FWIW I found this example more comprehensive: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2283/

Comment: Snippet doesn't seem to work for me anymore, fails on ForeignKey. Plus transaction is depreciated in favor of atomic. Plus iteritems() became items() in python3. (last two issues were easy to solve, first one not).

Comment: In solving the first issue I found out that the problem is likely with the groupobjectpermissions of django guardian. Could not solve it though :(

Comment: `_meta.get_all_related_objects` was deprecated in Django 1.8 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api

Answer (score 3):

Two libraries now exist with up-to-date model merging functions that incorporate related models:

Django Extensions' [merge_model_instances](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/merge_model_instances.html) management command.

[Django Super Deduper](https://github.com/mighty-justice/django-super-deduper/tree/master/django_super_deduper)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the snippet provided in the comments in the accepted answer, I was able to develop the following.  This code does not handle GenericForeignKeys.  I don't ascribe to their use as I believe it indicates a problem with the model you are using.

I used list a lot of code to do this in this answer, but I have updated my code to use django-super-deduper mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849578/603819). At the time, django-super-deduper did not handle unmanaged models in a good way. I submitted an issue, and it looks like it will be corrected soon.  I also use django-audit-log, and I don't want to merge those records. I kept the signature and the `@transaction.atomic()` decorator. This is helpful in the event of a problem.

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Model, Field
from django_super_deduper.merge import MergedModelInstance


class MyMergedModelInstance(MergedModelInstance):
    """
        Custom way to handle Issue #11: Ignore models with managed = False
        Also, ignore auditlog models.
    """
    def _handle_o2m_related_field(self, related_field: Field, alias_object: Model):
        if not alias_object._meta.managed and "auditlog" not in alias_object._meta.model_name:
            return super()._handle_o2m_related_field(related_field, alias_object)

    def _handle_m2m_related_field(self, related_field: Field, alias_object: Model):
        if not alias_object._meta.managed and "auditlog" not in alias_object._meta.model_name:
            return super()._handle_m2m_related_field(related_field, alias_object)

    def _handle_o2o_related_field(self, related_field: Field, alias_object: Model):
        if not alias_object._meta.managed and "auditlog" not in alias_object._meta.model_name:
            return super()._handle_o2o_related_field(related_field, alias_object)


@transaction.atomic()
def merge(primary_object, alias_objects):
    if not isinstance(alias_objects, list):
        alias_objects = [alias_objects]
    MyMergedModelInstance.create(primary_object, alias_objects)
    return primary_object
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Django 1.10. Hope it can serve.

```
def merge(primary_object, alias_objects, model):
"""Merge 2 or more objects from the same django model
The alias objects will be deleted and all the references 
towards them will be replaced by references toward the 
primary object
"""
if not isinstance(alias_objects, list):
    alias_objects = [alias_objects]

if not isinstance(primary_object, model):
    raise TypeError('Only %s instances can be merged' % model)

for alias_object in alias_objects:
    if not isinstance(alias_object, model):
        raise TypeError('Only %s instances can be merged' % model)

for alias_object in alias_objects:
    # Get all the related Models and the corresponding field_name
    related_models = [(o.related_model, o.field.name) for o in alias_object._meta.related_objects]
    for (related_model, field_name) in related_models:
        relType = related_model._meta.get_field(field_name).get_internal_type()
        if relType == "ForeignKey":
            qs = related_model.objects.filter(**{ field_name: alias_object })
            for obj in qs:
                setattr(obj, field_name, primary_object)
                obj.save()
        elif relType == "ManyToManyField":
            qs = related_model.objects.filter(**{ field_name: alias_object })
            for obj in qs:
                mtmRel = getattr(obj, field_name)
                mtmRel.remove(alias_object)
                mtmRel.add(primary_object)
    alias_object.delete()
return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to merge records in Django Admin, and found a package that is doing it (https://github.com/saxix/django-adminactions).

**How to use:**

Install package:
`pip install django-adminactions`

Add adminactions to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'adminactions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.messages',
)
```

Add actions to `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.admin import site
import adminactions.actions as actions

actions.add_to_site(site)
```

Add service url to your urls.py: `url(r'^adminactions/', include('adminactions.urls')),`

Tried it just now, it works for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19976026)

Comment: Mmm... Not sure I understood what would be the better way to write my answer... I just wanted to help others who is the same as me wants to use a ready solution rather than writing own code.

Comment: Best practice is to post the code that worked to solve the problem, especially with some explanation of why it works.  Someone may refer to this answer years in the future, when the link you used is no longer active... I have even found my own answers on stackexchange to use from five years ago...  :)

Comment: I see. Ok. It's just in this particular case I can't post all the code, as it is a package that is doing all the job. But I added instructions on how to install this package (which are copy pasted from the package's documentation)

Comment: @J.Win. please check if looks better now, I made some changes :)