# Merging models, Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-orm

After upgrading from Django 1.8 to 1.11 I've been looking at a means of merging some records - some models have multiple entries with the same `name` field, for example. There's an answer here that would appear to have what I would need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291137/1195207

I tried it with models like this:

```
class GeneralType(models.Model):
    #...
    domains = models.ManyToManyField(Domain, blank=True)
    #...

class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    #...
```

...where `Domain` has various records with duplicate names. But, it fails at the point indicated:

```
def merge(primary_object, alias_objects=list(), keep_old=False):
    """
    Use this function to merge model objects (i.e. Users, Organizations, Polls,
    etc.) and migrate all of the related fields from the alias objects to the
    primary object.  This does not look at GenericForeignKeys.

    Usage:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    primary_user = User.objects.get(email='good_email@example.com')
    duplicate_user = User.objects.get(email='good_email+duplicate@example.com')
    merge(primary_user, duplicate_user)
    """

    # ...snip....

    for alias_object in alias_objects:
        for related_object in alias_object._meta.related_objects:
            related_name = related_object.get_accessor_name()
            if related_object.field.many_to_one:
                #...snip...
            elif related_object.field.one_to_one:
                #...snip...
            elif related_object.field.many_to_many:
                related_name = related_name or related_object.field.name
                for obj in getattr(alias_object, related_name).all():
                    getattr(obj, related_name).remove(alias_object) # <- fails here
                    getattr(obj, related_name).add(primary_object)
```

The problem is apparently that `'GeneralType' object has no attribute 'generaltype_set'`. Adding a `related_name` to GeneralType doesn't fix this - the script fails in the same manner but quoting the name I've now given it. I'm not quite sure what Django is up to here so any suggestions would be welcome.

Edit:

In a Django shell I can successfully reference GeneralType from Domain, so it's something about the script above that I'm not getting. Example:

```
>>> d = Domain.objects.first()
>>> d
<Domain: 16s RNA>
>>> d.generaltype_set  
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x11175ba90>
>>> d.generaltype_set.first()
<GeneralType: Greengenes>
>>> getattr(d,'generaltype_set')
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10aa38250>
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and the code for your models? It's not clear what the relation between Domain and GeneralType is. [mcve]

Comment: could you please elaborate what alias_objects refer to? Domain objects or Generaltype objects?

Comment: Apologies, I'm away at the moment and can't respond with the requested info., but will attempt to do so as soon as I can tomorrow. Whether I can make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example is another matter, though - this is a bloated Django application, after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a workaround. It seems that everything would function if I referenced `generaltype.domains` in the `getattr(obj, related_name)` part of the script, so I modified it as follows just before the line marked as failing in the question above:

```
if obj.__class__.__name__ == 'GeneralType':
    related_name = 'domains'
```

Everything ran as it should after that, it seems.